# Put sum after row end and apply to all sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with multiple worksheets with different names. I wanted to put a sum after the last row of columns A & B and I want it applied to all worksheets in the workbook. Also, I would need that sum to be in bold and highlighted in yellow.

Please help me with the appropriate VBA Macro

EDIT:

I saw this code here too, but this will only put a sum on a single sheet with a predefined sheet name of Sheet1. My sheets are named differently. I would need a macro that would apply what this does to all sheets irrespective of the sheet names.

```
Sub test() 
    Dim ws as worksheet 
    Dim VR as Long 
    Dim rng as Range

    Set ws = Thisworkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")  
    With ws
        VR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Row  
    End with

    Set rng = ws.Cells((VR+1), 10)  
    rng.Offset(2,0).Formula ="=SUM(J2:J" & VR & ")"
End Sub
```

Comment: Please don't write in all upper-case. It's considered shouting or yelling. And shouting at the people you want help from is rather rude. Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Please share the code you have tried.

Comment: Hi nshit dey, I edited my post to include the code that I think would work but only for a single sheet.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to use the FIND() function as described [here](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/7/7/5-different-ways-to-find-the-last-row-or-last-column-using-vba)

Moreover, you seem to be actively targeting column 10 to put your sum below the last value. The column count could change in the future. To make it more robust, you could either check the column names or always put the sum below the last column of your range. I´d also suggest to use subtotal instead of the SUM function 109, again, just to make it more robust.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to loop through all your worksheets

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets  ' loop through all worksheets
    ' find the last used row in column A in each worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    ' one below last row write the sum formulas
    ws.Cells(LastRow + 1, "A").Formula = "=SUM(A2:A" & LastRow & ")"
    ws.Cells(LastRow + 1, "B").Formula = "=SUM(B2:B" & LastRow & ")"
Next ws
```

Comment: Side note:+) Writing adjacent sum formulae it would suffice to resize a single target & assign the first formula string via `ws.Cells(LastRow + 1, "A").Resize(1,2).Formula = "=SUM(A2:A" & LastRow & ")"`

Comment: @T.M. Yes, that would be even more elegant :)

Answer (score 1):

### Add Totals to Columns of Data

```vb
Sub AddTotals()
    
    Const FirstRowAddress As String = "A2:B2"
    Const EmptyRowsBetween As Long = 0
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lCell As Range
    Dim rCount As Long
    Dim sAddress As String
    
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        With ws.Range(FirstRowAddress)
            Set lCell = .Resize(ws.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
                .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
            If Not lCell Is Nothing Then
                rCount = lCell.Row - .Row + 1
                sAddress = .Resize(rCount).Columns(1).Address(, 0)
                With .Offset(rCount + EmptyRowsBetween)
                    .Formula = "=SUM(" & sAddress & ")"
                    ' To get rid of the formulas use:
                    '.Value = .Value
                End With
            Else
                Debug.Print "No relevant data in worksheet '" & ws.Name & "'."
            End If
        End With
    Next ws
    
    MsgBox "Totals added.", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```

Comment: This just did the job perfectly! Thank you so much! :)

Just an added question, how do I insert a script to make the summations on all tabs boldfaced and highlighted?

Comment: Right below `'.Value = .Value` use: `.Font.Bold = True` and e.g. `.Interior.Color = vbYellow`.